# Standard deviation...

Tags: probability, statistics, standard-deviation

I have this random variable $X = \{-1, 0, 1\}$ with uniform repartition $p(X = -1) = p(X = 0) = p(X = 1) = \frac{1}{3}$.

Expected value is $$E[X] = \sum_{i\in\{-1,0,1\}} x_ip_i = 0$$

Then variance should be : $$Var[X] = \sigma_{_X}^2 = \sum_{i\in\{-1,0,1\}}(x_i-E[X])^2p_i = (-1-0)^2\times\frac{1}{3} + (0-0)^2\times\frac{1}{3} + (1-0)^2\times \frac{1}{3} = \frac{2}{3}$$

And the standard deviation : $$\sigma_{_X} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \simeq 0.82$$

But according to Scilab and my phone, the standard deviation is actually $1$...

So what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You did it correctly.  Those two bits of software did a different thing correctly: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Corrected_sample_standard_deviation ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: This business of subtracting $1$ is done ONLY when estimating a population standard deviation based on a sample.

Answer (score 1):

It looks correct and I get the same results as your calculation with numpy.

> import numpy as np
>
> x = [-1,0,1]
>
> np.std(x)
>
> 0.81649658092772603

So it is probably the way you calculate it.

Comment: Well that's weird... "x = [-1,0,1]; stdev(x)" yields 1 on Scilab, standard deviation fonction on my phone also says 1, and Wolfram|Alpha too : http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=standard+deviation+{-1%2C0%2C1}

Comment: It seems to be difference between sample or population standard deviation, in wolfram it shows one, and then says "Assuming "standarddeviation" is sample standard deviation | Use as population standard deviation instead", where if you click on that one, it gives you the expected number.

Comment: You could read the details on wiki, (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Corrected_sample_standard_deviation)

Answer (score 1):

Note $$\operatorname{Var}[X] = \operatorname{E}[X^2] - \operatorname{E}[X]^2 = \operatorname{E}[X^2] = \Pr[X^2 = 1] = \frac{2}{3}.$$  The first equality comes from the calculation $$\begin{align*} \operatorname{Var}[X] &= \operatorname{E}[(X-\operatorname{E}[X])^2] \\ &= \operatorname{E}[X^2 - 2\operatorname{E}[X]X + \operatorname{E}[X]^2] \\ &= \operatorname{E}[X^2] - 2 \operatorname{E}[X]\operatorname{E}[X] +\operatorname{E}[X]^2 \\ &= \operatorname{E}[X^2] - \operatorname{E}[X]^2. \end{align*}$$  The second equality holds because $\operatorname{E}[X] = 0$ as you calculated.  The third equality arises because of the definition of expectation, and observing that if $X \in \{-1, 0, 1\}$, then $X^2 \in \{0,1\}$, and the final equality is because $\Pr[X^2 = 1] = \Pr[X = 1] + \Pr[X = -1]$.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there are two types of standard deviation:

[sample standard deviation :](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=standard%20deviation%20%7B-1%2C0%2C1%7D)

and

[population standard deviation :](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=population%20standard%20deviation%20%7B-1%2C0%2C1%7D)

which is confusing because it was never introduced in textbooks...

Comment: Depends on which textbook.  Certainly there are textbooks that contain this.